# iTunes In App Purchases and the User Dialog

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, itunes

My iPhone app includes a subscription service for a web server, which Apple insists that I make available as an in-app purchase. However I not entirely happy about the way the user dialog pans out. Some time after the app submits the purchase to iTunes, the user gets a confirmation request from iTunes. But this could happen at any time after the purchase is submitted.

I am wondering whether my app should pop up an alert, after the submission is made. Is there a standard procedure for this? If the confirmation request comes back straight away, then the user would see two alerts one after the other, which could be confusing. On the other hand, if he is going to have to wait a while, it would be nice to let him know that this is the case.

Is there a standard procedure for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think standard procedure would be to disable user interaction and show a spinner, or otherwise let the user know that the transaction is pending. You can then handle the purchase if it comes back, or implement a timeout and then show a pop-up notifying the user that the transaction could not be completed.

If you really don't want to make the user wait for completion before continuing in the app, I would put your notifying pop-up before you send the request. So when the user presses the button, you pop-up and say "This may take a while", and when they press "OK", THEN you send the request. Personally I don't think this is particularly good UX though, since in the majority of cases it will not take very long.

Comment: No, I would not want to do that at all. What I do at the moment is to pop the view controller off the navigation stack when the user taps the Submit button. That way the user does get some feedback.